# Может ли `free` отработать с ошибкой

Tags: c

Допустим есть кусок кода:

```
char *ptr = (char*)malloc(needed_size);
if (!ptr) {
   error_handling();
} else {
   do_something_without_freeing_ptr();
   free(ptr);
   ptr = 0;
}
```

Может ли вызов `free` не отработать/отработать неправильно и к каким последствиям это может привести?

---

Подразумевается, что между вызовом `malloc` и `free` выделенная память не освобождается, значение указателя не изменяется.

Не лучше ли, во избежание случайного изменения значения `ptr`, писать:

```
char * const ptr = malloc(needed_size);
```

Это не избавит от возможности написать `free(ptr); free(ptr);`, но по крайней мере убережет от чего-то типа `ptr = NULL;`

Comment: А почему вообще возникла мысль, что может?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`free` определена как функция, не возвращающая значений, т.е. возможности вернуть ошибку у неё нет. Если ей передать указатель полученный не от `calloc`, `malloc`, `realloc`, либо вызвать  повторно для одного и того же указателя или изменить байты за пределами запрошенного массива, действия зависят от реализации. Обычно это приводит к непредсказуемым ошибкам в программе, возможно в совершенно другом месте. Такие ошибки трудно локализовать.

К примеру, в начале выделенного куска памяти перед тем, на что указывает указатель, обычно находится заголовок — структура с информацией об этом куске и о следующем. Кроме этого, где-то может быть информация о свободных кусках. Если, например, в результате функции `gets()` будет испорчен заголовок для следующего блока, то проявиться эта ошибка может даже не когда этот блок будет выделен `malloc`, а когда этот блок будет освобождаться.

Есть библиотеки реализующие набор функций `calloc`, `malloc`, `realloc`, `free` с дополнительными средствами обнаружения их ошибочного использования.

Написать `char * const ptr = malloc(needed_size);` можно, но это не гарантирует, что вы не скопируете указатель в другую переменную или примените индекс за пределами [0; needed_size[.

Comment: То, что вызов `free` для "неправильного" указателя может (должен) приводить к UB - понятно. Интересно как раз, может ли закрэшиться корректный вызов `free`.

Comment: может, если в do_something_without_freeing_ptr что-то записать за пределами needed_size, т.е.когда индекс >= needed_size или <0

Comment: хмм, но ведь ptr лежит в стэке (пусть он локальный в main), а то, куда он указывает - в куче. Можно ли некорректной работой с кучей изменить память в стэке?

Comment: @sercxjo: Ну это технически тоже UB.

Comment: @andy.37: UB отменяет все гарантии. В C нет понятия правильности конкретного вызова, есть лишь правильность всей программы в совокупности. Это приводит к такому себе «дальнодействию»: ошибка в одной части программы приводит к неправильному поведению в другой, не имеющей с первой, казалось бы, ничего общего. (И да, это очень сложно отлаживать.)

Comment: Память в стеке вряд ли измените, но за пределами выделенной памяти в куче лежит информация об этой самой куче, нечаянно изменив её можно нарушить работу malloc/free.

Comment: @andy.37, дополнил ответ

Comment: @sercxjo, ага, спасибо, уже сам разобрался, и даже собрался писать вставленный Вами абзац в качестве собственного ответа.

Answer (score 5):

Согласно Стандарту `C11` (7.22.3.3/2):

> The **free** function causes the space pointed to by **ptr** to be deallocated,
>   that is, made available for further allocation. If **ptr** is a null
>   pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a
>   pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the
>   space has been deallocated by a call to **free** or **realloc**, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Т.о. если память была корректно выделена и не была после этого ещё освобождена с помощью `free` или `realloc`, всё должно быть хорошо.

Если провести некоторую параллель с `c++`, то необходимость отсутствия ошибок в функции `free` чем-то сродни необходимости не бросать исключения в деструкторах.

---

На счет дополнительного `const` к указателю - идея хорошая и правильная. Позволяет выявлять ситуации непреднамеренной модификации или повторного использования переменной в разных контекстах. Главное здесь, не переборщить и не завалить код `const`ами там, где от этого совсем нет профита.

С другой стороны, невозможность изменить значение указателя на `NULL` будет препятствовать защите от повторного освобождения. Т.к. если указатель мутабельный, можно писать так и не бояться последствий:

```
T* ptr = malloc(/*...*/); 
// ...
free(ptr);
ptr = NULL;
free(ptr); // Безопасно
```

Понятно, что для `T* const ptr` такое будет невозможно.

Answer (score -2):

Насколько мне известно, стандартный С не позволяет контролировать неконсистентный heap и вообще какие-либо ошибки при освобождении памяти.

Поэтому нужно пользоваться или возможностями используемой операционной системы, как `GetProcessHeap`, `HeapAlloc`, `HeapFree`, `HeapValidate` под Windows или расширениями используемого компилятора, см. 
 [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx) и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx).

Comment: А откуда вообще могут взяться ошибки освобождения памяти, которые надо "контролировать"? И как вы их "контролировать" собрались?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Наиболее стандартная проблема: выход за границы при записе в один аллокированный блок делает дескриптор блока памяти следующего аллокированный блока неверным. В результате запрос на освобождение памяти блока `ptr`, в работе с которым в коде нет никаких ошибок, не работает. Вторая ситуация более простая, но, все же важная. Если по окончании работы прграммы в нипе оказались неосвобожденные блоки памяти, то как найти где в программе эти блоки были аллокированы. Именно в таких случаях помогает техника, каторую с упомянул в моем ответе.

Comment: И как вам `HeapAlloc` поможет искать место в программе, которое эту ошибку вызвало? Напротив, инструменты динамического анализа работают с "родной" кучей языка, а не с кучей WINAPI.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Это стандартная техника, но ее объяснение не такое кароткое, особенно если писать с помощью виртуальной клавиатуры :-). Напимер, вставляется вызов `HeapValidate` в конце программы. Если выясняется, чно есть коррупция хипа, то дальше вставляется вызов `HeapValidate` в разные места программы. Намример, перед и после вызова подпрограммы. Если до вызова подпрограммы хип в порядке, а после нет, то нужно спускаться в подпрограмму и встаслять вызовы `HeapValidate` в подпрограмму. Так можно достаточно быстро локазиловать постоянно репродуцируемую коррупцию хипа.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Естественно реальность намного сложнее и нередко проблемы возникают лишь в экзотических ситуациях, нак exceptions без соответствующего __try __finally блока. К тому же дажно различать дра вида коррупции хипа: коррупция хипа операционной системы (malloc испольует внутри HeapAlloc при ваботе под Windows) и коррупцию хипа C/C++ runtime. В последнем случае незаменимы другие функции из расширения компиляторов, которые я упомянул. Меня удивляет, что многие, похоже, вообще не знакомы с проблемами, о которых я пишу. Они намного глубже банального изменения указаталя, но весьма реальны.