# Как возвращать указатель на локальную переменную в функциях?

Tags: linux, c, указатели

В моей программе в некоторых функциях возвращается указатель на локальный массив. Все идеально работает.

Но проблема ведь в том, что после завершения работы этой функции этот массив должен был разрушиться. Почему все работает и через указатель возвращается информация из функции?

Еще, я так понимаю, тут возникает утечка памяти?

Если внутри функции использовать динамическое выделение памяти, то как использовать `free()`, если нужно вернуть указатель на эту память и функция завершит свою работу. 
Глобальные переменные использовать не хочу.

Comment: Лакальные переменные находятся в стеке, вы в принципе можете продолжать пользоваться этой областью памяти до тех пор пока этот участок стека что нибудь не затрет. А затереть его может вызов любой функции или даже аппаратное прерывание, которое может произойти в любой момент.

Comment: Ну так если Вы использовали динамическое выделение памяти и у Вас есть на нее указатель, так и используйте free(). В чем проблема?

Comment: @MaxZS согласен... В принципе и за пределами функции это сделать можно! Спасибо.

Comment: а можно сделать как делают в линуксах и виндах. В описании функии говорят - она выделяет память. Для освобождения используйте нашу функциию. А та внутри просто вызывает free.

Comment: @Mike спасибо! теперь понял, почему работает

Comment: Да, и утечки памяти не будет. Будет UB. И нормальные компиляторы ругаются на такое `int * f() { int a[5]; return a; }`

Comment: @andy.37 я создал локальный указатель char*, присвоил ему значение, и функция возвратила этот указатель. Компилятор не ругается.

Comment: @MaximGusev тут все зависит от того, какое именно значение Вы ему присвоили.

Comment: @MaximGusev компилятор и не обязан ругаться. Просто в c/c++ достаточно много ситуаций, которые делать нельзя, но компилятор при этом будет молчать, т.к. по Стандарту диагностика не требуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Память, выделенная при помощи `malloc` доступна откуда угодно из программы, и она остаётся выделенной до тех пор, пока не освободится при помощи `free`, либо пока работа процесса не завершится. Освободить память при помощи `free` можно из любого места программы, главное передать указатель на ту же область памяти, который вернула `malloc`. Но если вы возвращаете указатель на участок памяти, был выделен локально, но не через `malloc`, то вы получите неопределённое поведение вашей программы.

```
int * my_func()
{
    int *x = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    //int x[10]; - так нельзя, память под этот массив будет освобождена при выходе из функции,
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int *x = my_func();
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался. Но тогда придется заводить новый указатель (чтобы подать его в free), если раньше я мог сразу подставить функцию вместо переменной. Хотя есть неоспоримый плюс - избавляемся от неопределенного поведения.

Comment: Не только для результата от `malloc` можно вызывать `free` (см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494233/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-free-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9))

Answer (score 2):

По возвращении из функции память специально никто не затирает, но и не сохраняет. Очередной вызов - и память может оказаться затерта. Или не затерта, как повезет.

Можно объявить локальный массив как `static`, тогда он останется сохраненным между вызовами функции. Минус этого решения - в том, что второй вызов этой функции может изменить массив, указатель на который вы уже один раз вернули. Если в вашей задаче это не страшно - можно так.

Если же это не устраивает - то выделяйте массив в динамической памяти, возвращайте на него указатель; главное - потом не забудьте в вызывающей функции вызвать `free()`. И всегда тщательно документируйте такие функции - чтобы не забывать освобождать память. Увы, C - не C++, тут идиома RAII не работает..